# JNI GetObjectField() returns NULL for one of two DirectByteBuffers

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Ok, this one is boggling my little mind.

I get a null return from one of two calls to GetObjectField(). Each object is a DirectByteBuffer. The call does not throw an exception for failure to find the field, but it returns NULL all the same.

Here's the peculiar part - if I change the order of the definition of the fields in the inner class, I see the null change from source to dest.

Here's a paraphrase of the code to reduce the problem to the essence.

```
public class Outer {
  private native int submitInner(Inner submission);

  private static class Inner {
    private int status;
    private ByteBuffer source;
    private ByteBuffer dest;
    private Outer outer;


    Inner(Outer outer, ByteBuffer source, ByteBuffer dest) {
      this.outer = outer;
      this.source = source;
      this.dest = dest;
      status = 0;
    }
}
```

Native code. I'm clipping away the field id's here for brevity. Suffice it to say that the problem moves from one field to the other without touching these, so presumably the field id's are fine.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_Outer_submitInner
(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisj, jobject inner ) {
  jobject source = (*env)->GetObjectField(env, thisj, Inner_source);
  jobject dest = (*env)->GetObjectField(env, thisj, Inner_dest);
  jobject outer = (*env)->GetObjectField(env, thisj, Inner_outer);
  printf("%016llx %016llx %016llx\n", (long long)source, (long long)dest, (long long)outer);
...
```

Anybody have any ideas to make sense out of this?

Any suggestions for debugging it? I'm walking through the java from eclipse. Is there any way to walk through the C or assembly language to see what's really going on?

Thanks,
    - Tim.

Comment: What is the Java declaration of submitInner()?

Comment: Right. It appears the baby went out with the bathwater. I updated the original snippet to add that declaration, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are looking for fields of Inner but you're supplying an instance of Outer (thisj) as the place to get them from.

Comment: Wow, I really am that stupid. Thanks so much for catching that!